# When a theater performance took its start

Tags: verbs

How to say properly in English that a theater performance took its start?

Do they say:
1) 'The play has begun.'
2) 'The play has started.'
3) 'The play has been started.'
Or if none of the three sentences above is correct, then how?

Comment: #1 and #2 are fine.  #3 is grammatically correct but sounds strange, because it's in the passive, and it means that *somebody else* has started the play, which is probably not what you mean.

Comment: There's another expression: *The play has opened*, meaning that the play has had its premiere / is now being performed.

Comment: We tend to say, "The curtain went up eight", or "Curtain (time) is at  eight." I know that is not the question, but that is the example you chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to use:

> The play has begun/started.

(Both the words appear to be right...)

"The play has been started." sounds a little odd... As in, it's as if (the) play has been started for the season. If this is what you meant, it's correct.

Play has been defined as:

3. (Noun): a dramatic work for the stage or to be broadcast.

(More at: 
https://goo.gl/search/Definition+of+play)

Comment: Alex89 said in the title that this was a theater performance, so your comments about "play" as opposed to "the play" are irrelevant.

Comment: My bad... Sorry... Didn't see it... Only read the body of the question....

Comment: @AbhigyanChattopadhyay - That's why I often exhort ELLers to write their question in the body of the question, not in the title. I will edit and fix this...